# Can I have multiple research jobs totalling > 1.0 FTE in the United Kingdom?

Tags: research-process, working-time

Is it permitted in UK academia to have more than one Research Associate post which totals greater than 1.0 FTE? *. What's the general opinion if no definitive answer is possible.

Obviously 2.0 FTE would be a stretch, but I was thinking more along the lines of 1.2 FTE or 1.3 FTE.

- FTE = full-time employment.

Comment: It's basically not allowed in the US to get more than 1.0 FTE from the federal government in grant funding. The rest depends on each local institution's rules for outside work. No single institution that I know of will give you more than 1.0 FTE worth of salary, though the workload may seem higher than that!

Comment: I don't know if you can, but are you sure it is wise? If people being paid for 1 FTE in practice end up working 1.2-1.3, you would be putting yourself at 1.4-1.7 FTE!

Comment: @BillBarth Re *No single institution that I know of will give you more than 1.0 FTE worth of salary* - Not necessarily. I am currently employed at 1.14 FTE (1.0 FTE as a research assistant and 0.14 as an adjunct) from the same department. (None of my current salary comes from federal grant funding.)

Comment: @ff524, huh. Your profile says that you are a  PhD student. Is your assistantship 20 hours/week or 40?

Comment: @BillBarth (nominally) 20 hours

Comment: @ff524, that is not an FTE. In this context, one full-time equivalent would be 40 nominal working hours a week. Now as a student, the other half of your time is probably supposed to be as a full-time student (9-ish credit hours for US grad students). So that might make you "working" in some sense 40 hours a week, but you're only being paid for 20 which is 0.5 FTE. Adding your 0.14 adjunct position makes you 0.64 FTE.

Comment: @BillBarth [This is my payroll profile](http://i.imgur.com/5L7H4Gz.png) for the research assistant job. The payroll/HR system considers it to be 1.0 FTE

Comment: @ff524, that's unusual for a 20-hour a week appointment. Your university appears to be an outlier.

Comment: In the UK, how many hours you work can depend on grade, e.g. Higher grades state 35 hours whilst lower grades are 37.5 or more :-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in UK academic institutions, you are paid based on your "grade" on the pay scale (for posts up to but not including professor). If you were asking if you would receive more than 1.0 FTE in pay, I believe the answer is no, as you would no longer be on the regular scale. Your pay is based on your post, and the research funding would contribute to the University's costs and overheads, as well as your pay. The HR office would not let you be paid more than you should receive according to their calculations.

If you mean holding more than one Research Associate post, while still receiving the same pay, this depends on your institution. I have many colleagues working on multiple projects simultaneously. They're putting in more than 1.0 FTE of effort. As to their official FTE, I believe thy are officially 1.0 FTE, and they are a Research Associate "for" a given member of staff. Their time is then "unofficially" (for want of a better term) split between multiple projects.

I am sure this will vary between funding sources and institutions, as to what is tolerated/the norm. In this case I reference, however, this is not a case of holding multiple RA posts; rather holding a single post, which works on multiple projects. Since their post is not tied strictly to a single project, the FTE is perhaps not the best metric to gauge them by.

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite common at UK institutions to offer a 20% FTE position to non-UK academics to beef up the REF return. These people have at last 1.2 FTE employment, and possibly have more positions.

When academics are evaluating or reviewing for funding agencies (e.g. European Commission) or engage in external examination duties, they also have a (limited time) contract with other employers taking them over 1 FTE. This is often explicitly allowed in the employment T & Cs, as activities comprised within the university's core business.